# How do I make text length adjust to page width?

Tags: html

I have a pre element with some really long text, and it shows as a singlee line and widens the page. How do I make it break the line when it reaches the end on the screen?

Answer (score 2):

Use `white-space: pre-wrap`.

```css
pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<pre>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</pre>
```